# Compilation error when upgraded from Angular 4 to 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I have upgraded recently from Angular 4 to 5 and I get the following error on compilation:

[image: CompilationError]

The following is how my Package.json file looks after upgrade:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12"
    "angular2-moment": "^1.6.0",
    "atob": "^2.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "primeng": "^4.2.1",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "quill": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the upgrade. I went through some of the issues posted in Git but was of no help.Could you please let me know how I could fix this issue.

Comment: Near impossible to read, please post the stack trace text here.

Comment: Can you please include your tsconfig.json as well?

Also, did you try reinstalling all your npm packages? (delete `node_modules/` & `package-lock.json` and run `npm i`)?

Comment: @AmitB. I have included tconfig.json. Yes I did delete the entire node modules folder and then executed npm install but still did not work for me.

Comment: Check the changelog between 4 and 5, I think that the issue is on the modules, they change the names between versions and also when you refer for rxjs just import 'rxjs' and try to avoid 'rxjs/whatever'